# How do I change a single letter in a grid (array of strings)?

Tags: python, string, list

For a given input of a grid of numbers, what is the best way to be able to change just one number to a letter (in my case, "X") and then returning the same grid?

Here's code we can't touch - how the input is handled:

```
grid = []
for _ in range(n):
    grid_item = input()
    grid.append(grid_item)
```

And for our function, we take in this grid as our argument

The grid will look something like

```
246
345
159
```

and I want to change a number, say the middle 4, to an "X"

I know I can't do

```
grid[1][1] = "X"
```

because the input is as a string. I think I have to change it to a list first, and then change it to "X" and then change it back to a string?

but supposing I have to write a function that will traverse through the grid -

```
for i in range(len(grid)):
    for j in range(len(grid[0])):
        if blahblah:
             grid[i][j] = "X"
```

is the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish...how do I do it correctly?

Comment: you'd better provide examples of the input and output for the function you want to implement. So others can be more easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
grid[i] = grid[i][:j] + "X" + grid[i][j+1:]
```

As a side note, you should also change the following line:

```
for j in range(len(grid[0])):
```

to

```
for j in range(len(grid[i])):
```

Comment: Good point for 
```
for j in range(len(grid[i])):
```

just good practice; for my purposes it's just a square grid though so it's fine.

Using your method, would the for loop still function to move onto the next j after you do the grid[i][:j] + "X" + grid[i][j+1:] method?

Comment: Yes, there is no reason you can't perform multiple replacements using this method.

Answer (score -1):

You can see [Python: String replace index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38856180/python-string-replace-index), if you want to keep them as `str`.

If you really want to convert a list of strings to a list of lists, you can use

```
for i in range(len(grid)):
    gird[i] = list(grid[i])
```

Then, you can do `grid[i][j] = "X"`

Since any iterable object can be converted directly into a list using `list(iterable)`.

To convert back:

```
for i in range(len(grid)):
    gird[i] = ''.join(grid[i])
```

Comment: How would I do that in the context of a 2d array? (i.e. want to change grid[0][i] = "X")

Comment: Although the information is correct, this does not answer the question.

Comment: I editted my answer just now. I am a new contributor, and if I have make some mistakes, please tell me. By the way, it is not correct to call it a 2d array. To be exact, it is a list of lists.